# Clipping by canvas extent using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, clip

I am trying to clip my .tif image using qgis(Zanzibar) as before but having trouble to get it in .jpg or .jpeg as it appears black (as picture below) after the function is performed. I choose the option of Raster>Extraction>Clip Raster by Extent, which is not giving me the colored image that I had before clipping and saving it in .jpg format.

Is there any solution to get the clipped image in colored version in .jpg or any version that gives the small size of image?

[image]

Comment: I will suggest first save that raster file with checked "as rendered" options,  (at top of export window) . And clip that saved tiff.

Comment: I could not find the "rendered option" you suggested. Can you please make it more clear where to check the rendered option?

Comment: Kudos! I am able to make the image as per I wanted. Thank you for your worthy suggestion. It meant a lot to me.

Comment: if it help I added it as the answer to your question and pleas mark it as answer for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest first save that raster file with checked "as rendered" options,  (at top of export window) . And clip that saved tiff.